# Colour dots based on conditions in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, fill

I have this dataset

```
a <- data.frame(PatientID = c("0002" ,"0004", "0005", "0006" ,"0009" ,"0010" ,"0018", "0019" ,"0020" ,"0027", "0039" ,"0041" ,"0042", "0043" ,"0044" ,"0045", "0046", "0047" ,"0048" ,"0049", "0055"),
                   volume = c( 200 , 100 , 243 , 99 , 275, 675  ,345 , 234 , 333  ,444,  123 , 274 , 442 , 456  ,666 , 567 , 355 , 623 , 105 , 677  ,876), 
                   Status= c("New" , "Old" , "New" , "New" , "Old", "New"  ,"Old" , "New" , "Old" , "New" , "New" ,"New"  ,"Old" , "New" ,"New"  ,"Old" , "New" , "Old" , "New" , "Old" ,"Old"),
                   sex = c( 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0, 0  ,0 , 0 , 0  ,1 , 1 , 1  , 0 , 0  ,1 , 1 , 1 , 1  , 1 , 1  ,1), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

and this code

```
color <- c("#00B7EB","#EE2A7B")                
ggplot(a, aes(y = a$volume, x = a$Status, fill = a$Status)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_point(alpha=0.4) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=color) +
  labs(x='', y='Volume') +
  theme_classic() +
  theme( text = element_text( size = 15))
```

This, produces the following plot

[image]

**THE QUESTION:**

What can I do to colour the dots in this ggplot based on the following condition?:
If volume is >100 in women (sex==1) red, otherwise black
If volume is >200 in men (sex==0) red, otherwise black

Thank you so much!

Comment: Add a column to your data with that condition, then map that column in `aes(color = that_column)`. Also, you should break the bad habit of using `data$column` inside `aes()`. Change your code to `ggplot(a, aes(y = volume, x = Status, fill = Status)) + ...`

Comment: However, I would like to have only the boxplot associated with my status categories, and the only thing I want to colour is the dots, to know who is outside the normal range. Makes sense? I wonder if something like geom_point(aes(color = factor(label)) would work. But I am unsure how to write it correctly

Comment: So you put `aes(color = that_column)` inside the `geom_point()` layer, and it will only apply to that layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is by setting the colour aesthetic of geom_point to your condition:

```
geom_point(alpha=0.4, aes(colour = (sex == 1 & volume > 100) | (sex == 0 & volume > 200))) +
```

Then use scale_colour_manual to set the colours to red and black:

```
scale_colour_manual(values = c("black", "red")) +
```